# Make sure broadcast receiver never stops

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

So I have a repeating broadcast receiver that I want to be always running. I currently have it so that it starts on boot and it will also start when the app is launched. I want to make sure that it can handle any circumstances so that it will not get stopped. What I am most concerned about is the broadcast receiver stopping when the app crashes or the user force quits. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: If your app just crashes, it's not going to affect the state of your statically registered Receivers. If your app is forcibly stopped, though, the boot Receiver won't work until the user launches your app again. You can't really do anything about that.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I couldn't find a direct answer about this.